# Is there a way to capture the end of the event of Element.scrollIntoView()?

Tags: dom-events, js-scrollintoview

I'd like to flash the targeted element for three times after it being scrolled into view. I've looked up in the documentation however didn't find anything about capturing events. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks.